# How can you add a conditional statement to a =QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

How can I add a conditional statement (similar to an `if elseif` in .php) to the query listed below so that is will return columns D and E from Sheet2 if column C in the responses sheet == 1st or columns F and G if from Sheet2 if column C in responses sheet == 2nd? It must work within the `=QUERY` so it only returns column data from the appropriate row (based on the query).

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:K; CONCATENATE("SELECT B, C WHERE A = ", responses!B1), 0)
```

I looked into `IF(OR)`, but I don't believe that will work because final project will have more than two possibilities (there will actually be eight, 1st through 8th class period).

[Here is a link to the Google Spreadsheet I'm working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhNVNg1xSJ6-dGpvdFJGMmpuWExWeUE2SWhFQ21Wb3c&usp=sharing).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read. Could you provide an example of which input should generate what output?

Comment: Vidar, I'd like to add something like this `=if(C3=1st,"responses!D3",IF(C3=2nd,"responses!F3", "Missing Data"))` A nested IF statement that will pull celldata from the responses sheet from the row identified by =QUERY above. I'm not sure 'if' that is possible and 'if' it is, I'd like a little help including it in the =QUERY. Thank you!

Comment: This will solve all of your three questions, Btw....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following formula will display the corresponding teachers.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(array_expression)
=VLOOKUP(search_criterion, array, index, sort_order)
=IF(test, then_value, otherwise_value)
=SIGN(number)
=ROW(reference)

=ARRAYFORMULA(                           // ARRAYFORMULA start
   VLOOKUP(                              // VLOOKUP start
     B2:B,                               // search_criterion                 
     DATA!A2:G,                          // array
                                         // index start
     IF(                                 // IF start
       C2:C="1st",                       // test 
         {4,5},                          // then_value
         {6,7}                           // otherwise_value
     ) *                                 // IF end
     SIGN(                               // SIGN start
       ROW(                              // ROW start
         A2:A                            // reference
       )                                 // ROW end
     ),                                  // SIGN end
                                         // index end
     0                                   // sort_order
   )                                     // VLOOKUP end
 )                                       // ARRAYFORMULA end

// to copy / paste
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,DATA!A2:G,IF(C2:C="1st",{4,5},{6,7})*SIGN(ROW(A2:A)),0))
```

### Explained

The `SIGN` and the `ROW` function are there to meet up with the criteria, set with using an `ARRAYFORMULA`. It will return an equally long array as setout in the *search_condition*. The `IF` function sets the condition for the *index*, by using the *test*.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've copied your file and added my solution to it: **[teacher references](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At3L7K_lcLHydDFMdGUwWnp5eDJTb0lIN1ZVUTJnTHc&usp=sharing)**

Comment: Jacob Jan Tuinstra, Thank you! That worked PERFECTLY!